# How to see flipflops of state machine in Quartus II

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, quartus

I have a circuit created by `VHDL` code in Quartus II. There I have a state machine. I chose the type of encoding: `one-hot`. I have 9 states and so I should have 9 flipflops.

Is it possible to watch how Quartus implements them on scheme? I can see only state table.

Another question is how to use the outputs of these flipflops. I need to connect them to leds but I don't know how to find them.

If it's necessary I will add my code.

[image: Scheme]

Answer (score 0):

You can check your state machine in Quartus this way: `"Tools" -> "Netlist Viewers" -> "State Machine Viewer"`

You have to connect your LED output port(s) of your top level entity to the pins on your FPGA. You have to look up in the user manual of your FPGA which pins are used for LEDs. In Quartus you can choose `"Assigments" => "Assigment Editor"`

Example: [image: Assigment Editor]

Comment: Thanks, but about state maschine it's not what I need.